# Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic row heights with table view cell from universal storyboard

Tags: uitableview, ios7, autolayout, ios-universal-app

So far I've had some success in calculating dynamic table cell layouts with auto layout. And so far, I have maintained different storyboards for iPhone and iPad. I would now like to consolidate them into a single storyboard per app. I'm currently stuck at a point where my height calculations do no longer function.

The trouble is apparently that the table view cell as dequeued from the storyboard is still at its fixed storyboard size (relative to a specific device, i.e. iPhone in my case) when the calculation is first required. It will be resized to fit the actual device (iPad in my case) when the table is displayed. But `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called before that and therefore does its calculation based on the wrong table cell width.

Is there a good way to solve this problem? It seems as if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) accepted answer also isn't immune because its instructions also only mention the cell in isolation from its table view.

> First, instantiate an offscreen instance of a table view cell, one
>   instance for each reuse identifier, that is used strictly for height
>   calculations.

Comment: @smileyborg Could you (as the main author of the cited answer) please have a look at this? Thx.

Comment: Instead of relying on the table view's `bounds.size` to set the cell width, you could use the view controller's `view.bounds.size` instead (assuming your table view takes the full width, and that the view has already been correctly sized). Or, force the table view to take on the correct width in `viewDidLoad` (which will be before `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called).